# How should "have been" be translated?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, verbos

I often use the phrase "have been" (or "has been") in English in sentences like:

- It has been raining a lot recently.
- I have been thinking about the exam all week.
- It's been a long time since I've seen you.
- I have been very busy with work lately.

In Spanish I was told "have/has been" generally translates as *he estado* (or *ha estado*, etc). Are there other ways "have been" can be translated? When would each be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the examples you provide they can all be translated as *ha estado* or *he estado*, except the third one:

> - It has been raining a lot recently = Ha estado lloviendo mucho últimamente (or maybe better "ha llovido mucho últimamente")
> - I have been thinking about the exam all week = He estado pensando en el examen toda la semana
> - I have been very busy with work lately = He estado muy ocupado con el trabajo últimamente

Your third case is a bit special, because "It's been a long time" is kind of different. It translates as "ha pasado mucho tiempo" or "hace mucho (tiempo)". So:

> - It's been a long time since I've seen you = Hace mucho (tiempo) que no te veo

So, yes, in general *have been* translates as *ha estado* (or whatever person it is). I would say this applies to:

- have been + gerund
- have been + adjective

But there are some constructs, like "it's been a long time" that have a corresponding special construct in Spanish.

I must add that if what *has been happening* is still going on, or has just finished, you could say, for example:

> - I have been waiting for an hour = Llevo una hora esperando
> - Have you been doing that for a long time? = ¿Llevas mucho tiempo haciendo eso?